# Postscript syntax difficulty

Tags: postscript

Having difficulty trying to create a postscript file that will output differently based on a string at the beginning. I'm able to do the following and create a valid postscript file:

```
/x (string) def

  /Times-Roman findfont
  12 scalefont
  setfont
  newpath
  100 200 moveto
  (sdbc) show
```

Then, I try to wrap an if statement around it...

```
/x (string) def

x (string) eq {
  /Times-Roman findfont
  12 scalefont
  setfont
  newpath
  100 200 moveto
  (sdbc) show } if
```

And this creates an invalid postscript file. Any tips on postscript syntax to achieve this kind of thing would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Document Viewer on ubuntu which I believe is used as the interpreter.

Comment: Both files work fine (and give the same output) for me on Mac OS X. What error message do you get?

Comment: Indeed, nothing(*) wrong with the code.  *most of the time you don't need need `newpath`. It's a paranoid style.

Comment: I figured out that it was the interpreter. I ended up using ghostscript instead and everything worked fine. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 2):

String (and other composite) objects are the same **only** if they are the same object, not if their contents are the same. In C terms they are equivalent only if they are the same pointer.

So:

```
/x (string) def
/y x def
/Z (string) def
```

y equals x, z does not equal either x or y. If you want to test for the contents of the strings being the same, then you need to examine the character at each position individually using the get operator, there is no strcmp or similar operator.

The behaviour of composite objects is is an important and often overlooked point in PostScript.

Comment: Strings are different than arrays or dicts for comparisons. `gsnd -c '(abc)(abc)eq ='` prints `true`.

Comment: Not strictly relevant here, but strings are also different in that their contents are immune to the effects of `save` and `restore` (but not their existence). But strings have a distinct behavior in specific circumstances which doesn't follow directly from their composite nature. ....Your last sentence is definitely true. But the rest is a misgeneralization.

Answer (score 0):

It was ubuntu's document viewer - it is very touchy. Try using ghostscript if you run into this problem.